# HK2 factory for Quartz jobs, not destroying service after execution

Tags: java, dependency-injection, quartz-scheduler, hk2

I want to use [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) in my server application that uses [HK2](https://hk2.java.net/) for dependency injection. In order for Quartz jobs to have access to DI, they need to be DI-managed themselves. As a result, I wrote a super simple HK2-aware job factory and registered it with the scheduler.

It works fine with instantiation of services, observing the requested `@Singleton` or `@PerLookup` scope. However, it's failing to `destroy()` *non-singleton* services (= jobs) after they are finished.

**Question:** how do I get HK2 to manage jobs properly, including tearing them down again?

Do I need to go down the path of creating the service via `serviceLocator.getServiceHandle()` and later manually destroy the service, maybe from a [JobListener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/JobListener.html) (but how get the ServiceHandle to it)?

**Hk2JobFactory.java**

```
@Service
public class Hk2JobFactory implements JobFactory {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Inject
    ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

    @Override
    public Job newJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException {
        JobDetail jobDetail = bundle.getJobDetail();
        Class<? extends Job> jobClass = jobDetail.getJobClass();
        try {
            log.debug("Producing instance of Job '" + jobDetail.getKey() + "', class=" + jobClass.getName());

            Job job = serviceLocator.getService(jobClass);
            if (job == null) {
                log.debug("Unable to instantiate job via ServiceLocator, returning unmanaged instance.");
                return jobClass.newInstance();
            }
            return job;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            SchedulerException se = new SchedulerException(
                    "Problem instantiating class '"
                    + jobDetail.getJobClass().getName() + "'", e);
            throw se;
        }

    }

}
```

**HelloWorldJob.java**

```
@Service
@PerLookup
public class HelloWorldJob implements Job {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        log.info("I'm born!");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdown() {
        // it's never called... :-(
        log.info("And I'm dead again");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        log.info("Hello, world!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @jwells131313 suggestion, I have implemented a JobListener that `destroy()`s instances of jobs where appropriate. To facilitate that, I pass along the `ServiceHandle` in the job's `DataMap`.

The difference is only that I'm quite happy with the `@PerLookup` scope.

**Hk2JobFactory.java:**

```
@Service
public class Hk2JobFactory implements JobFactory {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Inject
    ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

    @Override
    public Job newJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException {

        JobDetail jobDetail = bundle.getJobDetail();
        Class<? extends Job> jobClass = jobDetail.getJobClass();
        try {
            log.debug("Producing instance of job {} (class {})", jobDetail.getKey(), jobClass.getName());

            ServiceHandle sh = serviceLocator.getServiceHandle(jobClass);
            if (sh != null) {
                Class scopeAnnotation = sh.getActiveDescriptor().getScopeAnnotation();
                if (log.isTraceEnabled()) log.trace("Service scope is {}", scopeAnnotation.getName());
                if (scopeAnnotation == PerLookup.class) {
                    // @PerLookup scope means: needs to be destroyed after execution
                    jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put(SERVICE_HANDLE_KEY, sh);
                }

                return jobClass.cast(sh.getService());
            }

            log.debug("Unable to instantiate job via ServiceLocator, returning unmanaged instance");
            return jobClass.newInstance();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            SchedulerException se = new SchedulerException(
                    "Problem instantiating class '"
                    + jobDetail.getJobClass().getName() + "'", e);
            throw se;
        }

    }

}
```

**Hk2CleanupJobListener.java:**

```
public class Hk2CleanupJobListener extends JobListenerSupport {
    public static final String SERVICE_HANDLE_KEY = "hk2_serviceHandle";
    private final Map<String, String> mdcCopy = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {
        JobDetail jobDetail = context.getJobDetail();

        ServiceHandle sh = (ServiceHandle) jobDetail.getJobDataMap().get(SERVICE_HANDLE_KEY);
        if (sh == null) {
            if (getLog().isTraceEnabled()) getLog().trace("No serviceHandle found");
            return;
        }

        Class scopeAnnotation = sh.getActiveDescriptor().getScopeAnnotation();
        if (scopeAnnotation == PerLookup.class) {
            if (getLog().isTraceEnabled()) getLog().trace("Destroying job {} after it was executed (Class {})", 
                    jobDetail.getKey(), 
                    jobDetail.getJobClass().getName()
            );
            sh.destroy();
        }

    }

}
```

Both are registered with the `Scheduler`.

Answer (score 1):

For Singletons:

Seems like a Singleton service would NOT be destroyed when the job is finished, because it is a Singleton, right?  If you *are* expecting the Singleton to be destroyed at the end of the Job then it seems like the service is more of a "JobScope" and not really a Singleton scope.

JobScope:

If "Jobs" follow certain rules then it might be an good candidate for an "Operation" scope (please see [Operation Example](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b36/operations.html)).  In particular jobs can be in an "Operation" scope if:

1. There can be many parallel jobs going at once
2. There can only be one job active on a thread at a time

Note that the above rules also means that Jobs can exists on multiple threads at the same or at different times.  The most important rule is that on a single thread only one Job can be active at a time.

If those two rules apply then I highly recommend writing an Operation scope that's something like "JobScope".

This is how you could define a JobScope if Jobs follow the rules above:

```
@Scope
@Proxiable(proxyForSameScope = false)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface JobScope {
}
```

And this would be the *entire* implementation of the corresponding Context:

```
@Singleton
public class JobScopeContext extends OperationContext<JobScope> {

    public Class<? extends Annotation> getScope() {
        return JobScope.class;
    }

}
```

You would then use the [OperationManager](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b36/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/extras/operation/OperationManager.html) service to start and stop Jobs when, you know, Jobs start and stop.

Even if Jobs do not follow the rules for an "Operation" you still might want to use a "JobScope" scope that would know to destroy its services when a "Job" comes to its end.

PerLookup:

So if your question is about PerLookup scope objects, you could run into some trouble because you probably need the original ServiceHandle, which it sounds like you wouldn't have.  In that case, and if you can at least find out that the original service WAS in fact in PerLookup scope you can use [ServiceLocator.preDestroy](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b36/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator.html#preDestroy(java.lang.Object)) to destroy the object.

Comment: As a side note, I just looked at the Quartz API, and I think you could easily use an OperationManager inside the JobListener methods "jobToBeExecuted" and "jobWasExecuted" to start and stop an hk2 operation, so it seems like a "JobScope" would work with Quartz

Comment: Thanks for the input; I'll look into Operations and the `OperationManage`. Of course, Singletons would not be destroyed after job termination - I didn't specify that well in the question.